# Swing: GridBagLayouts anchor does not work nested in an other GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am setting a first `GridBagLayout` to a main `JPanel`. To this Panel, ten other panels were added with this layout (outerConstraints). The sub-panels contains an amount of texts, which should be placed WEST with a new Layout and `innerConstraints`. But they center.

After testing a little bit, i found out that the texts / images ARE placed WEST, but only, if the `outerConstraints` do not fill the white panel horizontally. The problem is, that i can not remove this command, because i need every panel to have the same width.

Is there a possiblity to allow `outerConstraints` to fill up AND to make its nested `GridBagLayout` positioning the text left?

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

GridBagConstraints outerConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
outerConstraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
outerConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;    // seems to be reason, but needed.

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        outerConstraints.gridx = i % 2;
        outerConstraints.gridy = i / 2;

        JPanel agentVisitCard = new JPanel();
        add(agentVisitCard, outerConstraints);

        GridBagConstraints innerConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        innerConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;                 //fails
        innerConstraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        agentVisitCard.setLayout(layout);

        (...)

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Agent " + (i + 1) + ":");

        innerConstraints.gridx = 0;
        innerConstraints.gridy = 0;

        agentVisitCard.add(label, innerConstraints);
```

Agent 3 does not align left:
[image]

Comment: Try making the innerConstraints fill horizontal as well.

Comment: If that doesn't work, try setting the weightx to some non-zero value (1.0 would work fine).

Comment: Well, I can't really tell what you are doing. It looks like your code is trying to add 2 components to every row, but I only see 1. Your panels all look the same size to me, so maybe you should be using a GridLayout. Another option to make sure components align to the left, is to create a JPanel with a FlowLayout and LEFT_ALIGNMENT. So maybe you have a structure like main panel, flow panel, agent panel. In any case post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. For better help.

Comment: Second comment works. :) Thank you! I will accept your answer if you mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the anchor wasn't working is because the components had no weight. Without that, the area given to the component is only the minimum size needed, i.e. the size of the component itself, and no bigger.

Here is a quote from the [swing tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) (under the **weightx, weighty** section) that explains it:

> Unless you specify at least one non-zero value for weightx or weighty, all the components clump together in the center of their container. This is because when the weight is 0.0 (the default), the GridBagLayout puts any extra space between its grid of cells and the edges of the container.

By default, the weightx and weighty are 0, which is why it was not working for you. Since you only wanted to anchor it horizontally, setting the weightx to a non-zero value allowed that to work. If you wanted a vertical anchor, you would need to set the weighty as well.

An explanation of how the weightx and weighty values should be used follows that:

> Generally weights are specified with 0.0 and 1.0 as the extremes: the numbers in between are used as necessary. Larger numbers indicate that the component's row or column should get more space.

Although they recommend using values between 0.0 and 1.0, it is not necessary. Any `double` value will work. What's important is the ratio between the weights of components if you have several of them.